# Help choosing a PERC RAID card for a MD3000

Tags: raid, dell, configuration, dell-perc

I'm trying to select a PERC card to use with a PowerVault MD3000 (15 drives in RAID5). Is the 5/E the only card compatible with the MD3000 on sale by Dell at the moment - or are there newer better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the 5/E it is the only one supported.

Comment: please note that this should be a SAS 5/e card and not a PERC Raid controller card. This is critical!

Answer (score 2):

You must use the SAS 5/E NOT a PERC card, I repeat, a PERC card will not work with the MD3000 storage array, you require the PERC card for the MD1000 class array.

The RAID controllers are on-board for the MD3000 and therefore does not require an external controller.

Make sure that you have the Dell Modular Disk Storage Manager Client installed on your workstation and that you have connected both enclosure NICs to the same network as your workstation so that you can manage the arrays and drives.

Also note, the MD3000 enclosure does not support the Hot-Add of enclosures, you MUST powerdown the array before attempting to add another enclosure.

Comment: The SAS 5/E is under the PowerEdge RAID Controller (PERC) branding, so yes you want a "PERC SAS 5/E"

Comment: While it's true that the SAS 5/E is branded as under the PERC name, it's an unfortunate branding choice because the SAS 5/E is _not_ a RAID controller, it's a SAS HBA. I think Dan's point is only inaccurate in a marketing sense.